# Order Query by related table in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to order a query in laravel ways depending on certain factors. One of which would be a related table.

So right now my query goes like this:

```
$products = Product::where("price", "<=", $maxBudget)
```

and I know that I can add a function to my where clause like so

```
->where(function ($q) use($mature) {
    if ($mature == "1") {
        $q->where('mature', 1)->orWhere('mature', 0);   
    } else {
        $q->where('mature', 0);
    } 
})
```

however I want to make a function for my order as well. Something like this (I know this is wrong, this is just an example):

```
->orderBy(function ($q) use($orderBy) {
    if ($orderBy == "price_low") {
        $q->orderBy('price', 'desc');
    } elseif ($orderBy == "price_high") {
        $q->orderBy('price', 'asc');                    
    } elseif ($orderBy == "rating") {
        $q->orderBy( $product->user->getAvgStarRating(), 'desc')
    } else {
        $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
})
```

The `$q->orderBy( $product->user->getAvgStarRating(), 'desc')` is obviously wrong, $product isn't even defined, but you get the idea. In this scenario, I'd like to order my query based off the average rating of the creator of the product.

So my questions are: How do I make it so that I can add a function of some kind to my ordering, and how can I order a query based off related tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `user` relationship (if haven't already):

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Then you can use a modified `withCount()`:

```
Product::withCount(['user' => function($query) {
     $query->select('avgStarRating');
}])->orderBy('user_count', 'desc');
```

You can also use a simple JOIN:

```
Product::select('products.*')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', 'products.user_id')
    ->orderBy('users.avgStarRating', 'desc');
```

Comment: Hey Jonas. Thanks for the answer. Although it doesn't really work for me. I did define a user relationship, exactly as you said. However I get the error: "STATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rating' in 'order clause'".

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: I'm using version 5.4

Comment: What's the result of `dd(Product::withCount(...)->toSql());`?

Comment: `...` is just a placeholder: `dd(Product::withCount(['user as rating' => function($query) { $query->select('avgStarRating'); }])->toSql());`

Comment: "select `products`.*, (select `avgStarRating` from `users` where `products`.`created_by` = `users`.`id`) as `rating_count` from `products`"

Answer (score 1):

can you try this

```
$products = Product::where("price", "<=", $maxBudget)   
                    ->where(function ($q) use($mature) {
                        if ($mature == "1") {
                            $q->where('mature', 1)->orWhere('mature', 0);   
                        } else {
                            $q->where('mature', 0);
                        } 
                      })  
                    ->orderBy(function ($q) use($orderBy) {
                        if ($orderBy == "price_low") {
                            $q->orderBy('price', 'desc');
                        } elseif ($orderBy == "price_high") {
                            $q->orderBy('price', 'asc');                    
                        } elseif ($orderBy == "rating") {
                            $q->join('users', 'users.id', '=','products.user_id')->orderBy('users.avgStarRating', 'desc')
                        } else {
                            $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                        }
                    })->get();
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it gives me the error: "strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"